# Android prevent Activity from losing focus

Tags: android, android-activity, progressdialog

I'm currently working on an Application that does some heavy processing that can not be interrupted.  I was wondering if there was a way to prevent the user from starting another activity.

A little about the activity:

-It has a thread separate from the UI thread that does the processing
-It has a wakelock so the screen does not go to sleep
-It has a progress dialog that warns the user to not interrupt the processing

Another note, the application does detect when the Application does lose focus and logs out which is a security measure.  I was trying to decide weather the app should try to "gracefully" stop the thread (A lot of work involved and might be wonky) Or try what I am asking.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well no you cannot completely restrict user, As while there is a background thread running your user may receive a call too! So it depends...could you please let us know what exactly your background thread does? Like does it update your database directly?

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to ensure, that another activity won't start.
For really long background processing you should user service. In some cases you can also consider set this service as "foreground". Take a look at android reference for examples.